# Responsive header gets bigger than screen on mobile

Tags: android, html, ios, css, responsive

I have a fairly straightforward header on my website, seen here: [www.botlink.us](http://www.botlink.us).  It's designed to be responsive, so when I reduce the width of the page, it turns into a different header with an icon on the right that drops down the menu of links.  On my desktop it works beautifully.  Reduce the width of the page, the header comes in no problem.  When I switch over to a mobile device, however, for some reason the header width stays at 700 pixels, no matter what.  Any idea as to the cause?

(I'll refine this example with actual code when I have figured out what the precise cause is. For now, all the code is linked above.)

Comment: You probably need the viewport meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Comment: the code is linked above. The meta tag did not resolve it.

Comment: Links die and this site is self contained. Narrow down the issue to a small portion of code and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue was that lower down in my html I had an element (a div tag with a white background, so it blended in and was hard to catch since the elements inside the div moved over along with the rest of the page as the screen was narrowed) that was set wider.  I located the issue by searching through my CSS stylings for the string, '700px,' which was the width that the header was sticking to. I then located the code and was able to reconfigure the widths to resolve the issue.